# Count all elements in an array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, count

I have a table that I save some data include list of numbers.

like this:

| numbers |
| --- |
| (null) |
| ،42593 |
| ،42593،42594،36725،42592،36725،42592 |
| ،42593،42594،36725،42592 |
| ،31046،36725،42592 |

I would like to count the number elements in every row in SQL Server

| count |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 4 |
| 3 |

Comment: I don't think that SQL Server features arrays. Are you talking about comma-separated strings maybe? And if so, why do you store the numbers concatenated in a string rather than in a separate table as is common in realtional databases?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a replacement trick here:

```sql
SELECT numbers,
       COALESCE(LEN(numbers) - LEN(REPLACE(numbers, ',', '')), 0) AS num_elements
FROM yourTable;
```

The above trick works by counting the number of commas (assuming your data really has commas as separators).  For example, your last sample data point was:

```
,31046,36725,42592 => length is 18
310463672542592    => length is 15
```

Hence the difference in lengths correctly yields the right number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use`STRING_SPLIT`:

```
SELECT  y.numbers, 
(SELECT COUNT(Value) - 1
FROM string_split(COALESCE(y.numbers,''),',')) AS num_elements
FROM yourtable AS y;
```

I know this looks a bit unhandy on first glance due to this strange -1 in the second line and the `COALESCE` in the third line. So why do I talk about this option?

Well, the strange thing in your case which causes these difficulties in my query is that your rows always start with a comma.

This is quite weird and it would be much easier without this first comma in every row.

Let's assume you remove this comma in future. Then this will become really easy and good readable:

```
SELECT  y.numbers, 
(SELECT COUNT(Value)
FROM string_split(y.numbers,',')) AS num_elements
FROM yourtable AS y;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JTlJEGLq)

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable(
   numbers VARCHAR(max) 
);
INSERT INTO yourtable
(numbers) VALUES 
(null),
('،42593'),
('،42593،42594،36725،42592،36725،42592'),
('،42593،42594،36725،42592'),
('،31046،36725،42592');
```

you need `ISNULL` and `len`

```
select 
ISNULL(len(numbers) - len(replace(numbers,'،','')) ,0)  count
from yourtable
```

the other way is by using `IIF` and `string_split` as follows

```
SELECT IIF(count < 0, 0, count) count
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Count(*) - 1
                FROM   STRING_SPLIT (Replace(Replace(numbers, 'R', ''), '،',
                                     'R'), 'R'
                       )) AS
               'count'
        FROM   yourtable) A
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Zyp11wh)

Comment: That's just a bad variation of Tim's answer. Which purpose does your answer have? And no, you DO NOT need ISNULL. COALESCE is fine and I would prefer this because it's Standard SQL.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler   really appreciated I added another solution